# How to remove jQWidgets watermark in grid?

Tags: watermark, jqwidget

I use the non-commercial version of jQWidgets . When jQWidgets grid loads, a hyperlink "www.jqwidgets.com" appears for about two seconds and then disappears. How to remove watermark in the grid?

Comment: Purchase it? or maybe look in their forums or FAQs

Comment: Well, guys you should know that this is ILLEGAL

Comment: When you purchase the license, you will get access to a special customer portal site (login required). From there, you can download a production build .zip file as well as the pre-minified versions. They should also give you a password to be able to unzip any required files. This version will not have the watermark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

find the code:
String.fromCharCode(119,119,119,46,106,113,119,105,100,103,101,116,115,46,99,111,109)

in all files and replace it with ""

Comment: I tried this but it doesnt work , I am using jqxtreegrid with version v4.5.1 i found this code String.fromCharCode(119,119,119,46,106,113,119,105,100,103,101,116,115,46,99,111,109) in jqxdatatable.js file so i replaced it with "", But it doesnt work and still i can see watermark at the bottom right ..

Comment: Are you sure ? I used this method on the same version and it worked perfectly. Did you replaced it on all places because it apears more than once?

Comment: Well, guys you should know that this is ILLEGAL

Answer (score 3):

Review the Release for jQWidgets v4.1.2.

There says:

> Added watermark in major widgets for non-commercial & evaluation
>   versions. Non-commercial users may request a production build  without
>   the watermark by writing to sales@jqwidgets.com.

You can write to sales@jqwidgets.com and request the production package without watermarks, **but only for non-profit projects**.

Answer (score 3):

Well, I found a simple way to hide the watermark. In this way, you don't have to modify the source code of `jqwidgets`. You just need to write a simple css to override the color of watermark element. It will work for all version.

CSS to override the color:

```
    span[id^="jqxWidget"] 
    {
        color: transparent !important;
    }
```

You will find full example in the snippet.

```js
var data = generatedata(500);
 var source = {
     localdata: data,
     datafields: [{
         name: 'firstname',
         type: 'string'
     }, {
         name: 'lastname',
         type: 'string'
     }, {
         name: 'productname',
         type: 'string'
     }, {
         name: 'date',
         type: 'date'
     }, {
         name: 'quantity',
         type: 'number'
     }, {
         name: 'price',
         type: 'number'
     }],
     datatype: "array"
 };

 var adapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source);
 $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid({
     width: 500,
     theme: 'energyblue',
     source: adapter,
     sortable: true,
     filterable: true,
     showfilterrow: true,
     columns: [{
         text: 'First Name',
         datafield: 'firstname',
         columngroup: 'Name',
         width: 90
     }, {
         text: 'Last Name',
         columngroup: 'Name',
         datafield: 'lastname',
         width: 90
     }, {
         text: 'Product',
         datafield: 'productname',
         width: 170
     }, {
         text: 'Order Date',
         datafield: 'date',
         width: 160,
         cellsformat: 'dd-MMMM-yyyy'
     }, {
         text: 'Quantity',
         datafield: 'quantity',
         width: 80,
         cellsalign: 'right'
     }, {
         text: 'Unit Price',
         datafield: 'price',
         cellsalign: 'right',
         cellsformat: 'c2'
     }]
 });
 $('#jqxgrid').on('filter', function () {
     alert("The Grid has been filtered");
 });
```

```css
span[id^="jqxWidget"] 
{
    color: transparent !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://jqwidgets.com/public/jqwidgets/jqx-all.js"></script>
<link href="https://jqwidgets.com/public/jqwidgets/styles/jqx.base.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://jqwidgets.com/public/jqwidgets/styles/jqx.energyblue.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxgrid/generatedata.js"></script>

<div id='jqxWidget'>
    <div id="jqxgrid"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: But please remember, it's better to give the credit of the developer. They provided full version of the library, just showing a little info for a moment.

Answer (score 0):

With latest version (non-commercial), I've been able to remove the watermark by adding the following statement:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        jqx.credits = '12F129D4-0E1B-44B8-9BBB-BB4CF78CC6BA';

        // do wathever you want with the library there...
    });
</script>
```

Note that the token could be maybe be different for you. You just need search for it in js files.